# Printing from label printer in C#

Tags: c#, printing, label

I am beginner in programming in C#.

I need to create an application to generate/print a label from Cognitive label printer. From last few days, I had gone through number of document to learn how to print document, how usb printer works and so on. I am confused how to print data in proper format on label. But I didn't find any valuable material that explain me how to program for label printer.

Can anyone suggest me some material or sample program how to work with label printer.

Comment: Do you have any code at all yet?  Which model printer are you working with? What are you trying to print - text, barcodes, etc?  Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: You might want to look at 3rd party label products like [Loftware](http://www.loftware.com/products/printserver.cfm) or [Bartender](http://www.seagullscientific.com/aspx/bar-code-label-software.aspx)

Comment: @RQDQ: It's an Windows application. No, I don't have any code with me right now.

Answer (score 1):

Label printers come in two basic varieties: Ones that act like a normal printer with a small paper size and ones that take their own instruction codes via text.

If it's the latter, then (assuming you know the language) use the Generic/Text-Only driver.

There is some documentation [on Cognitive's site](http://www.cognitive.com/resources_Documentation.aspx) - the Programming Guides describe the language for the printers.

Comment: I am using Generic/Text-Only for Cognitive Printer. Also, I am able to print text from my program but I am not able to print in proper format and I don't know how to format text.

Comment: check out the link I posted... depending on what model printer you've got there should be docs there that'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this software SDK that might be of use:

http://www.tec-it.com/en/software/label-printing/label-software/labeling-sdk/Default.aspx

It isn't free, but it basically creates a system by which you can print pre-formatted labels to your printer using C# (or a number of other languages).  You can pass data into the label and then print it all from your code.  The software costs may be a small price to pay if it gives you the functionality you are looking for.  However, I would say that for a small application you might want to kludge something together rather than incur the expense.  It all depends on your situation.

Comment: Can you explain me what you are trying to say. I just go through the link you had posted but it gives description of use of SDK to generate label no programming stuff how to generate label is there.

Comment: @Mick - Sorry, I wasn't clear in my post so I updated it.  Basically, this is a software you need to purchase.  It would work wonderfully in doing what you want to do but it all depends on whether you want to invest in something or not.

Comment: no I am not looking for software I am looking for programming stuff.